# SAT 2 Math Two Variable Limit Calculus Inquiry

Tags: calculus, limits

I ran into this problem in a calculus section for the SAT II Math Subject test:

[image]

I simplified the problem by expanding and simplifying:

$$\frac{(x^2 - 2xh + h^2 - x^2 + h)}{h}$$

$$\frac{(x^2-2xh+h^2-x^2+h)}{h}$$

$$\frac{h^2-2xh+h}{h}$$

$$\frac{h-(2x+1)}{1}$$

I graphed $y=2(h-x)$ on Desmos, and it was a straight line with a negative slope that moved up and down the Cartesian plane as the variable $h$ was positive and negative, respectively. As $h$ approaches $0$ though, I am unsure of how it affects the $x$ variable since the whole line moves with it.

[image]

Comment: Hint: Find a derivative in the formula.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have only taken trigonometry course, so I am unfamiliar with how derivates work.

Comment: Seems like you accidentally turned the $h$ in the numerator into an $h^2$.

Comment: @Math1000 Thank you, it's fixed.

Comment: The $x$ variable is independent of the $h$ variable.  Your final answer may involve $x$, but not $h$.

Comment: That means the rest of your computation is wrong though ;)

Comment: @Math1000 Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{(x-h)^2+h-x^2}{h}=1 - 2 x$$ Your last step is incorrect it should be $h-(2x-1)$

Comment: How did you derive the answer of 1-2x from the simplification at the end of the process? [h-(2x-1)] is an expression, so I am confused.

Comment: just substitute $h=0$ for $h-(2x-1)=1-2x$.